# AWS EC2 - Present UK IP address for outgoing requests from server in AWS Ireland data centre

Tags: amazon-ec2, proxy, cloudflare

We have an application that monitors client websites and does some crawling.

We're looking to move the application to existing EC2 servers that we run, but testing suggests that we're going to have issues due to some websites presenting different content based on the IP address that a request comes from.

For example, requests from our instance based in Ireland are served responses containing € symbol instead of a £ symbol.

Also, we suspect that the location of our server may also affect SEO efforts.

My questions:

1. Does AWS EC2 provide any mechanism to control the country that instance appears to be located in.
2. Is there a UK proxy service (like cloudflare) that we can use to alter our public IP, that has decent bandwidth, for SEO purposes?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. I think no, but as a somewhat solution you can allocate several Elastic IPs in eu-west region, make tests and detect how all of them treated (UK or Ireland) and then assign these IPs to your instances.